# Chage separate part of element style attr

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div defined like this:

```
<div class="myclass" style="position: relative; height: 480; width: 320">
```

And I want to rotate it with jQuery. If it would be something like iframe which allowed to have `height` and 'width` attributes, I would do it like this way:

```
var $mydiv = $('#my_table').find('div.myclass');
var height = mydiv.attr('height');
var width = mydiv.attr('width');

$mydiv.attr('height', width);
$mydiv.attr('width', height);
```

But I can't do it with `style` attr. Look like I have to copy all content of `style` attribute and parse with regex ot something like this. It doesn't look good.

I'm not good at jQuery/js, so can't find out: is there a better and clean way to work with `style` attribute?

Comment: so are you basically asking how to change the height and width of your `div` (so the width becomes the height and the height becomes the width)

Comment: use [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the height and width or [`.css('height')`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) not `attr` - the attribute is style - your div has no height or width attribute

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/css. To rotate the element use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OP used the word *rotate*, but the code suggests that they are actually looking to just swap width & height.

Comment: @PeterB fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make changes to css like this:

```
var height = $('.myClass').css('width');
var width = $('.myClass').css('height');

$('.myClass').css({
   'width': height,
   'height': width
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a specified CSS property, use the following syntax: css("propertyname","value");
for example:

`$(".myclass").css("height", "400");`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change "width" and "height" of  block you have answer already, but if you want to rotate your block with it's content, function translate() in css can help you. In detail:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```
.myClass{
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```